# Worklight ant task using apache commons - where is this loaded from?

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I'm trying to diagnose a failure in my ant file when it runs a Worklight task. I have a small ant file containing a simple reference to a Worklight task. This works correctly.

```
<target name="rawBuildApplication"  >
    <app-builder 
        applicationFolder="${applicationSource}"
        environments="mobilewebapp"
        nativeProjectPrefix="xxx"
        outputFolder="${outputFolder}"/>
</target>
```

However when I invoke this ant file from a build control ant file (actually from the RTC build system) I get a failure (below), showing worklight failing to find an apache Java class. I assume there's some simple environmental difference, perhaps a classpath. It might help to figure it out if I knew where Worklight loaded the apache commons from. Right now I can't see anything in my environment in the case that works that points any apache Jar.

```
   myAntFile.xml:146: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteQuietly(Ljava/io/File;)Z
        at com.worklight.builder.util.BuilderUtils.<clinit>(BuilderUtils.java:672)
        at com.worklight.builder.config.UserBuildConfiguration$Builder.<init>(UserBuildConfiguration.java:203)
        at com.worklight.ant.builders.ApplicationBuilderTask.createBuildConfiguration(ApplicationBuilderTask.java:149)
        at com.worklight.ant.builders.ApplicationBuilderTask.execute(ApplicationBuilderTask.java:80)
```

Edited: the cause is the use of -lib to add the RTC toolkit directory, exactly why this clashes and how to work around yet to be determined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually means you have version of the commons jar in your classpath, and its overriding the one packaged in the worklight-ant.jar.   the apache commons files are inside the worklight-ant.jar file

Additional info from djna: I can confirm that when adding the Rational Team Concert (RTC) 3.0 toolkit to the ant classpath, either explicitly with -lib, or when selecting that option in the RTC Build definition some conflicting commons jars are added to the classpath. Worklight packages the classes it needs in its jar, but the -lib folder seems to take precedence.

My workaround is to replace the conflicting jars with later ones. I used these jars

```
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-codec-1.8.jar
httpclient-4.2.5.jar
httpcore-4.2.4.jar
httpmime-4.2.5.jar
```

I guess the other alternative is to upgrade to a newer RTC, but in our environment that's not currently possible.